# Как вывести диаграммы в Wordpess

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте как вывести такие диаграммы в Wordpress что бы их можно было редактировать через админку когда верстал использовал плагин "circliful.js" ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин [WP Circliful](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-circliful/).